# heroku run rake db:migrate Error `block in method_missing'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

I get an error when trying to migrate db to heroku:

In one of my migration files I used to have a line that seemed to be a typo "rU" on line 8 so I just erased it thinking that it was the root of the error. But it is not.

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    t.string :first_name
    t.string :last_name
    t.string :profile_name
    rU //This is the line I removed, but still get the same error message. 




==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:users)
-- rU()
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined local variable or method `rU' for     <DeviseCreateUsers:0x007fa6ef156fd8>/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-   3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:465:in `block in method_missing'
```

Comment: It definitely looks like that line is still there if you still get that error. Make sure to git add and commit that change and redeploy to heroku and migrate again.

Comment: I just checked and it is not on local or git. I already pushed to Github the changed before.

Comment: you pushed to github? not heroku?

Comment: I have been pushing to github since I created the app. I have been testing the app locally and no problem. Today I want to place it online. So I pushed the app to heroku. The app is already on heroku, but since I work with sqlite3 on local I needed to switch to another ddbb for heroku. I set the Gemfile to use 'pg' ddbb on production. An then tried "heroku run rake db:migrate" and it is where I am stucked. thanks

Comment: did you run git push heroku master again after you committed your changes? You need to push to heroku.

Comment: No I didnt! Good catch. I just pushed now to heroku and then run "heroku run rake db:migrate" I now get another DDBB mirgration error: PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "credits" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "credits" ADD COLUMN "assigned_by"

Comment: try running: "heroku run rake db:schema:load" first and then migrate again.

Comment: It worked! Thanks Diego! It feels so good to know there is someone out there to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the syntax is a bit off.

If you want to just add some columns to an existing 'users' table:

```
add_column :users, :first_name, :string
add_column :users, :last_name, :string
add_column :users, :profile_name, :string
```

If you are creating the table 'users':

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "profile_name"
end
```